# Get related (via ForeignKey) object in my view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model like this:

```
class database(models.Model):
  db_name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=20)
  server = models.ForeignKey(dbServer, unique=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In my view I want to grab every database realated to the current user (has to be logged in at that point).
I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use:

```
some_user.database_set.all()
```

How ever I recommend trying related_name attribute, for example:

```
class database(models.Model):
    db_name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=20)
    server = models.ForeignKey(dbServer, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="databases")
```

And then:

```
some_user.databases.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [backwards relationship](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
databases = User.database_set.all()
```